# undefined index in search function

Tags: php

```
<?php

//capture search term and remove spaces at its both ends if the is any
$searchTerm = trim($_POST['name']);

//check whether the name parsed is empty
if($searchTerm == "")
{
    echo "Enter name you are searching for.";
    exit();
}

//database connection info
$host = "localhost"; //server
$db = "name"; //database name
$user = "root"; //dabases user name
$pwd = ""; //password

//connecting to server and creating link to database
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

//MYSQL search statement
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";

$results = mysqli_query($link, $query);

/* check whethere there were matching records in the table
by counting the number of results returned */
if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1)
{
    $output = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $output .= "Name: " . $row['name'] . "<br />";
        $output .= "Matric: " . $row['matric_no'] . "<br />";
        $output .= "Email Address: " . $row['email_add'] . "<br /><br />";
    }
    echo $output;
}
else
    echo "There was no matching record for the name " . $searchTerm;
?>
```

what's wrong with my code?how can i solve that problem??can somebody help me?
here is the error

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\foundation\testing.php on line 16

Comment: Is your form element named? I.e.: `name="name"`. If not, there's your answer. More specifically `<input type="text" name="name">` Plus, is your method set to POST and not GET?

Comment: Which one is line 16?

Comment: line 16 refer to---$searchTerm = trim($_POST['name']);

Comment: You are sure the 'name' is sent via POST and not GET ? Can we see the html form code?

Comment: Do read my first comment. Show your form too.

Comment: Fred... ya, i already named my form element..

Comment: here is my html code                                             <html>
<h1>Search By Name</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
  <label>Name:
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please don't dump code into comments - edit your original post and add the code there.

Comment: Ok, there's the problem `<form action="" method="post">`. You need to use `isset` when running entire code from inside the same page. **Always be specific** when asking a question and show full code including HOW you're using it as well as the form etc.. So, next time and if there is a next time, do "do" that.

Comment: okk,, I got it! thanks a lot! Fred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that variables are set before attempting to use them.

```
if ( isset($_POST['name']) ) {
    $searchTerm = trim($_POST['name']);
    // The rest of your code... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to store the form submitted values such as POST or GET, it is really a good habit to check if the value is really sent. You have to use [`isset`](https://www.php.net/isset) to check the same.

Example for POST type:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
  $searchTerm=trim($_POST['name']);
}
else
{
  // The user have not filled the <input name='name'> do something for empty
}
```

Example for GET type:

```
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
  $searchTerm=trim($_GET['name']);
}
```